# Swift Alamofire VS AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

I am developing an app using Swift. I want to call a REST API. I found there are two popular libraries, AFNetworking and Alamofire. But I don't know which is better (is more popular or has more features).

Can anybody suggest what are the main differences between Alamofire and AFNetworking?

Comment: Both are equal. For Swift you can use Alamofire and for Objective-C you can use AFNetworking.

Comment: try both and benchmark for your application.  if you're not using a lot of functionality write  you own based on benchmark and remove the bloat.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use `AFNetworking` if you use Objective-C

Use `Alamofire` if you use Swift

Comment: @Puvanarajan which method?

Comment: what if you are building an app that uses both objective C and swift

Comment: @hariszaman I'd recommend use Alamofire and then use a bridge for objective C code base. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: @Arsen it doesn't work out of box you have to implement some wrapper

Comment: Alamofire does not provide all the features btw.

Answer (score 88):

[`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and [`Alamofire`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) are by the same people (the [Alamofire Software Foundation](http://alamofire.org/)), `Alamofire` is their Swift version whereas `AFNetworking` is the Objective-C version.

Feature wise they are the same.

Comment: +1 for addressing the OP's actual question (what are the main differences) and providing more information than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you are developing app using `Objective-C` then you must go with the [AFNetworking.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Other wise if you are developing with the `Swift` then try the latest release of [Alamofire.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

In both the libraries Networking is done asynchronously. Only difference is Alamofire is no longer supported on iOS 7 due to the lack of support for frameworks.

Answer (score 9):

AFNetworking:

- This is the objective -C version of the library.
- This is very powerful and you could install this in your Swift project and use it as a bridge to the swift project.

Alamofire:

- This is the Swift version of AFNetworking.
- But not all the features of AFNetworking are included.

If you are good at Objective-C use AFNetworking. If not, use Alamofire. It is simple and many resources are available for Swift.

Answer (score 5):

**AFNetworking** is an Objective-C networking library for iOS, macOS and tvOS. It is a robust library that has been around for many years. From basic networking to advanced features such as Network Reachability and SSL Pinning, AFNetworking has it all. It is one of the most popular iOS libraries of all time with almost 50 million downloads.

**Alamofire** is AFNetworking’s successor but is written in Swift.  The two libraries share a similar feature set, with the main difference being the language in which they are written.

If you are starting a brand new Swift project, my recommendation is to use Alamofire so that your core networking library is consistent with your own source code. Otherwise, both AFNetworking and Alamofire are great options.

Source : Raywenderlich