# AFNetworking Migration Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

I'm trying to make an HTTP POST request to my own server using AFNetworking:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.post(
        URL,
        parameters: params,
        success:
        {
            (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

            if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: response["status"],
                                              message: response["message"],
                                              preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {_ in })
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        },
        failure:
        {
            (operation, error) -> Void in
            self.handleError(error as NSError)
        })
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
post(_:parameters:success:failure:) is deprecated
```

I searched the AFNetworking migration guide but that seems to only provide instructions in Objective-C, not Swift. I cannot find the new post method in Swift. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is written in Swift, why don't you use the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)?

As [@luke-barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/422287/luke-berry) explained:

> AFNetworking and Alamofire are by the same people (the Alamofire
>   Software Foundation), Alamofire is their Swift version whereas
>   AFNetworking is the Objective-C version.
>
> Feature wise they are the same.

See [Swift Alamofire VS AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988412/swift-alamofire-vs-afnetworking?answertab=oldest#tab-top) for more information.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> post(_:parameters:success:failure:) is deprecated
> ```

The non-deprecated version adds `progress:`. So in Swift you use `post(_:parameters:progress:success:failure:)` as in this example:

```
manager.post(URL, parameters: params,
                    progress: nil,
                     success: { (operation, responseObject) in },
                     failure: { (operation, error) in })
```